# SocketException: connection was aborted by your host computer software

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, tcp, raspberry-pi

I have written typical TCP/IP program (a c# client on unity3d and a python server on raspberry).the client sends commands to the raspberry through buttons, and the server responds to it by exciting relays. When i run the server and connect the client to it for the first time, everything is doing well, but if i close connection on the client and then i reconnect it to the server and click on any button, the command is sent but the connection is closed on the server and i couldn't send another command only if i re-run the server. And it shows that error message on unity :" SocketException: connection was aborted by your host computer software"
Anyone could help me to solve that problem?
this is my unity code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Control : MonoBehaviour
{

public string IP = "192.168.8.100";
public int Port = 6704;
public byte[] dane;
public Socket client;
public InputField inputfield;
public int etat;
public string data;
public byte[] data1;
public Text display;




public void Forward_Click()
{

    data = "1";
    data1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    client.Send(data1);


}
public void Back_Click()
{


    data = "2";
    data1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    client.Send(data1);


}
public void Right_Click()
{

    data = "3";
    data1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    client.Send(data1);


}
public void Left_Click()
{


    data = "4";
    data1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    client.Send(data1);

}
public void R_Turn_Click()
{

    data = "5";
    data1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    client.Send(data1);



}
public void L_Turn_Click()
{


    data = "6";
    data1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    client.Send(data1);

}

public void FR_Click()
{


    data = "7";
    data1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    client.Send(data1);


}

public void FL_Click()
{
    data = "8";
    data1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    client.Send(data1); }

public void OnRelease()
{ data = "0";
    data1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    client.Send(data1);
    Debug.Log("button not pressed");
}

 public void Connecting()
{
client =
new Socket(AddressFamily. InterNetwork, 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    client.Connect(IP, Port);
    display.text = "got connection";
    Changing();


}


public void Changing()
{ byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int k = client.Receive(b);//recive data from port coming from python script 
    string szReceived = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b, 0, k);
    if (client.Connected)
    {
        Debug.Log("Getting data from Python ");
        Debug.Log(szReceived);//showing data on the unity log
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(" Not Connected");

    }
}


void Start()
{
        }

void Update()
{

     }
}
public void Disconnect()
{
    client.Close();
    display.text = "Disconnect";
}
```

}

Comment: Hello, can you please show us the part of your sourcecode?

Comment: @Leon there is my unity code